# Why it is not possible to cast the result of Arrays.asList() to ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, interface, downcast

Return type of Arrays.asList is List and casting it to ArrayList is throwing an error. ArrayList is a child implementation class of List.So, Casting List to ArrayList will be downcasting. Then why below 1st line is throwing Run time error.

```
ArrayList<String> list  = (ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList("Amit","Suneet","Puneet");// Run time Error
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>(list);
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Can't we perform downcasting with interface and implementation class? If can then how?

Comment: Downcasting does not always succeed, you know.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question that deserves more consideration.  The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64344883/348975 raises the obvious question why did the java implementers create two ArrayList implementations.  java.util.Arrays.ArrayList (private) and java.util.ArrayList.  Without reading the code, it seems pretty dumb to me.

Comment: @emory, that should be a separate question.  The question as posted is pretty directly answered by the duplicate.

Comment: However, in general you should not be downcasting.  That is a bad coding practice and should be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

You can *only* downcast from `Foo` to `SubFoo` if the object actually being referenced is of type `SubFoo`.  If the object is of type `OtherSubFoo`, you will get a `ClassCastException`.

That is the situation here.  There is a class (private, as it should be) called `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`, which is different from `java.util.ArrayList`.  The object is of type `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList`, so it can't be cast to `java.util.ArrayList`.  The same thing would happen, for example, if it were a `LinkedList`.